# Why is SDIO used with WiFi chips

Tags: wifi, sd, sdio

SDIO standard is specifically meant for devices like camera that have an SD card. Still in many of the applications I found that the SDIO is also used to interface with WiFi chips. Why is that so? Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: Would you care to justify your initial statement?. My first response is 'No it wasn't. Although related, SD-Card & SDIO are not the same thing.'

Comment: What else would you use SDIO with? Because you certainly wouldn't use it for SD cards...

Comment: I suspect this started more with early PDAs that needed to support sd cards, and extending the protocol as a miniature module socket, perhaps in a second channel and then on-board made sense.  Today you see SDIO wifi in a lot of low cost tablets, that are somewhat the heirs to the role of those PDAs.